# I want to run any .exe. The program is processing but not opening

Tags: c#

I want to run any .exe. The program is processing but not opening. It pretends to be opening but not opening.
Picture: https://prnt.sc/swgg23

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = DosyaYolu;
            process.Start();

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
            file.Filter = "Exe files (*.exe)|*.exe|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            file.FilterIndex = 1;
            file.RestoreDirectory = true;
            file.CheckFileExists = false;
            file.Title = "Exe Dosyası Seçiniz..";

            if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // dosya seçildi ise
                DosyaYolu = file.FileName;
                DosyaAdi = file.SafeFileName;
            }
            label1.Text = DosyaYolu;
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by it _pretends_?

Comment: I mean "as if working".

Comment: Run it as `Process process = Process.Start("filename");` or set ProcessStartInfo as `process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("filename"));`

Answer (score 0):

I made like your code, and its work for me as well, lets try like it and it will be work :)
(I try under Console(.NET Core) App, not .NET Framework. Maybe it matters.)

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.FileName = @"C:\appname.exe";//Your appname
        Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Ithink also work on Form app, just .NET Core https://prnt.sc/swh7xm

Comment: I've never used it before. I will investigate and try.